# remove all spaces from specific field separated by comma

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

**Input:**

```
11 22 33 44,1 2,2
```

**Output**

```
11223344,1 2,2
```

I'm looking to remove all spaces in field number `1`, which is before the first `comma`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`, you'd either need a loop:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/^\([^,]*\) /\1/;t1'
```

Or use the hold space so as to be able to replace all the spaces and then recover the original part of the line from there:

```
sed 'h;s/,.*//;s/ //g;G;s/\n[^,]*//'
```

It comes easier with `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{gsub(" ", "", $1); print}'
```

Or `perl`:

```
perl -F, -lpe '$F[0] =~ s/ //g; $_ = join ",", @F'
```

or:

```
perl -pe 's{[^,]*}{$& =~ s/ //gr}e'
```

or:

```
perl -pe 's/\G[^, ]*\K //g'
```

That last one maybe deserves an explanation: `\G` goes with the `g` flag.

The `g` flags means to substitute `g`lobally and implies a loop where `perl` resumes searching for the next occurrence right after the previous one.

`\G` matches at that place just after the previous match, so after the last replaced space, and in the first pass in the loop, at the start of the line. As we're using `[^,]` we don't allow the loop to get past the first comma, so replacing all spaces before it only.